# laravel phpunit testing expecting status code 201 but received 302?

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I have a simple `PostController` with a `store` method that receives data, validates it, stores it and then redirects to `/posts` with a success message.

I have written a test to ensure that the post is created and saved as follows:

```
/** test */
public function testStore()
{
    $user = factory('App\User')->create();

    $post = factory('App\Post')->create(['user_id' => $user->id]);

    $response = $this->actingAs($user)
                    ->json('POST', '/notice', $post->toArray())
                    ->assertStatus(201)
                    ->assertJson([
                        'created' => true,
                    ]);

}
```

But I am receiving **301(redirection)** instead of **201**. I do not understand this.

Comment: in yoour controller instead of redirect use return response.May be solve you problem

Comment: You mentioned that the controller method will redirect to `/posts` so therefore you should expect a redirect status code.

Comment: But the code 201 is for resource created. Also on laravel docs they have shown the example with status 201. So I thought it first gives a status code of 201 before redirecting.